# Docker does not build image

Tags: docker

I just got started with docker and was following [fireship's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAkwW2tuIqE) tutorial, however I encountered a problem when I ran the `docker build` command. I was expecting a similar output as the video [(timestamp)](https://youtu.be/gAkwW2tuIqE?t=400). Instead, I got the following:

[image: output]

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app #maybe its this? There is no /app directory
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

ENV PORT=8080
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

#### `docker build` command

```
docker build -t <my docker id>/firstapp:1.1 .
```

#### File tree

```
D:/
 Code/
  testing/
   Docker/
    test1/
```

#### Notes

- Yes, I have a docker ID.
- **The docker build command stopped at `COPY . .`, rather than finishing at `CMD ["npm","start"]`**
- CWD (Windows): `D:\Code\testing\Docker\test1`
- I ran the `docker build` command twice

#### Questions

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can it be fixed?

Comment: `WORKDIR` creates the directory if it doesn't exist. It's not that.

Comment: What problem did you encounter? It looks like it worked...?

Comment: What's the error message?  I wouldn't expect `docker build` to write out a PNG file typically.

Comment: The issue is that you run on Windows and he runs on Linux and the output from `docker build` looks different on the two platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this occurs is because fireship is running Linux (like Hans Kilian noted) and I am running Windows. To get your image ID, run the `docker images` command, which will list your images w/ their image ID.
**However, I am still not sure why it does not complete all 8 steps.**

Comment: Instead of putting [SOLVED] in the title, you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).